# How to allow multiple file types direct download (bzip2 and csv) in RSelenium

Tags: r, selenium, selenium-firefoxdriver, rselenium

The following snippet allows us to perform direct download only for bzip2 file:

```
require(RSelenium)
dirdownload <- "/path_to/my_output_dir"
fprof <- makeFirefoxProfile(list(browser.download.dir = dirdownload,
                                 browser.download.folderList = 2,
                                 browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting = FALSE,
                                 browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk = "application/x-bzip2"))
RSelenium::startServer()
remDr <- remoteDriver(extraCapabilities = fprof)
```

Especially this line:

```
browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk = "application/x-bzip2"
```

How can I allow `makeFirefoxProfile` to include `application/bzip2`  **and** `text/csv` files?

I tried this but failed:

```
browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk = c("application/x-bzip2", "text/csv")
```

Comment: What about `browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk = "application/x-bzip2", "text/csv"` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk = "application/x-bzip2,text/csv,text/plain,application/json,application/zip"
```

It should work as a comma separated list within the double quotes